# Prisma: Concat String in SQL WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, prisma

I am using Prisma and PostgreSQL for the Nestjs backend.

In PostgreSQL and Mysql, I wrote the query below to fetch data using string concatenation. How can I implement this in Prisma?

```
    SELECT * FROM tbl_country, tbl_user WHERE CONCAT(tbl_country.code, '-', tbl_user.phone) = '+976-00000000';
```

---

*tbl_country*

```
| id  | name          | code |
| --- | ------------- | ---- |
| 1   | Afghanistan   | +93  |
| 2   | Aland Islands | +358 |
| 3   | Albania       | +355 |
| ... | ...           | ...  |
| 240 | Yemen         | +967 |
| 241 | Zambia        | +260 |
| 242 | Zimbabwe      | +263 |
```

---

*tbl_user*

```
| id  | name       | phone    |
| --- | ---------- | -------- |
| 1   | John Doe   | 11111111 |
| 2   | Bob Doe    | 22222222 |
| 3   | Adam Doe   | 33333333 |
| ... | ...        | ...      |
| 8   | Jane Doe   | 88888888 |
| 9   | Tom Doe    | 99999999 |
| 10  | Thomas Doe | 00000000 |
```

---

I read the [Prisma docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#examples-43) and found that I can use [raw query](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access#%EF%B8%8F-string-concatenation) in Prisma. But I want to implement it without raw query.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not supported natively yet, you would need to use [Raw Query](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access) for now. This use case could be achieved soon through [Prisma Client Extensions](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/15074)